# Running BOOST unit tests from Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c++, unit-testing, boost-test

I am just starting to work with [QuantLib](http://quantlib.org/index.shtml) project. There are quite a few BOOST unit tests defined, hence the question: is there an easy way to run these tests selectively from Visual Studio (and see results)?

I've only used unit testing in .Net languages so far, and there you can either use the built-in test runner if you use MsTest, or some add-on (I used Resharper and TestDriven.NET) for other frameworks. There you can choose which tests you run, and you can run them with the debugger attached (which is unfortunately useful sometimes). Are there similar add-ons for BOOST tests in unmanaged C++?

Comment: You can run and debug a Boost::test application like a normal executable. Also, I also found useful to have the tests run as a custom post build step (the results show up nicely in the output window of VS).

Comment: @AlexandreC., I think they did set it up as a post-build step as well. Can I run selected tests (i.e. the ones I am currently working on) only though?

Comment: See http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/libs/test/doc/html/utf/user-guide/runtime-config/run-by-name.html

Answer (score 4):

Yes you can!

If your boost unit test project is defined correctly, then you can run the entire test project from VS10 debugger by clicking

```
right click on project --> Debug --> Start new instance
```

This will run the tests inside VS framework which will give you all the debugger goodies.

For running specific test suites/cases, just edit the project command line arguments under

```
right click on project --> Properties --> General --> Debugging
```

and add the parameters according to the links in the other answers

Answer (score 3):

you can run any test case or test suite via command line. [running tests by name](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/libs/test/doc/html/utf/user-guide/runtime-config/run-by-name.html)

it even allows wildcards.

Comment: Nice. Is there any GUI add-in for VS to automate the process?

Comment: no, just the VS onboard project properties dialog. just add $(TargetPath) as custom post build event and you will be pointed to the failing tests in the output window (and error list). if you do not want to run all tests you have to name the tests/suites. by nice naming you may run multiple suites of your own via wildcard.

Answer (score 1):

[ReSharper C++](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper-cpp/) supports discovery and selective running/debugging of Boost tests (with Boost 1.59 and later).

Answer (score 0):

I'm using the Boost Unit Test Adapter. It's free and has a very nice output. It can also list the time the single tests consumed and you can start single tests and group of tests.

You can download it here:

https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/5f4ae1bd-b769-410e-8238-fb30beda987f?SRC=VSIDE