# can't debug UT since it causes compilation failure

Tags: c++, unit-testing

I am writing a new UT in my code (C++, VS10).
Apparently there is an error somewhere in the test. I see the following error in the compilation console

```
unknown location(0): fatal error in "Test1": breakpoint encountered
```

I want to debug the test to see what is wrong, but I can't, since this test failure cases the compilation to fail, and prevents me from running the code inside VS debugger.

I guess I can copy my code to the main() function, but this is problematic since the test requires many includes that are absent from that part. 
Is there any other option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `DebugBreak` inside `Test1`. It will crash and then you can attach the application to debugger. However, if debug information is not generated, you have to debug through assembly code.

Simple usage of `DebugBreak`

```
DebugBreak(); //Include Windows.h for it.
```

Comment: Well, it is simpler than that. I just needed to disable the post-build event that runs the unit-tests. This way I could run them myself in the debugger (as explained here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13935025/running-boost-unit-tests-from-visual-studio-2010/24106266#24106266) and just find where the code crashes
but your solution works perfectly good as well.
High five